# `If` condition with multiple `And` does not get the expected result

Tags: vba, if-statement, commandbutton, msgbox

Using a conditions to allow a button, I still didn't get the expected result. The button is not taking into account the conditions mentioned. How come

```
Private Sub CONFIRM2_Click()
    
    If NAMEC.Value = "" And DATEC.Value = "" And CREF.Value = "" And SPN.Value = "" And AMENDT.Value = "" And LINKA.Value = "" And BUDGETI.Value = "" And TOR.Value = "" And LINKA.Value = "" And DETAIL.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Thanks to fill all requested informations"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf NAMEC.Value <> "" And DATEC.Value <> "" And CREF.Value <> "" And SPN.Value <> "" And AMENDT.Value <> "" And LINKA.Value <> "" And BUDGETI.Value <> "" And TOR.Value <> "" And LINKA.Value
```

Some additional info: I added a field (TOR) into the conditions, but the MsgBox (MsgBox "Thanks to fill all requested informations") below does not take into account that additional field. Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question an add the relevant code part or a [mcve]? Also describe in words what the code should do. • Note that the message box only appears if **all** values are empty (that is what your `if` condition is).

Comment: It should be Or rather than And to check if any of the textboxes haven't been filled in.

Comment: Thx: what you mentioned about the msg box (last line of your comments) made me think deeper. I found the solution. many thx and have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

### `Select Case` Instead of `If`

```vb
Private Sub CONFIRM2_Click()
    
    Select Case ""
    Case NAMEC.Value, DATEC.Value, CREF.Value, SPN.Value, AMENDT.Value, _
            LINKA.Value, BUDGETI.Value, TOR.Value, DETAIL.Value
        MsgBox "Please fill in all of the requested information."
        ' Do whatever.
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Thanks for supplying the requested information"
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

**A Simplified Version**

```
Sub SelectCase()
    Select Case ""
    Case Range("A1").Value, Range("A2").Value
        MsgBox "Nope" ' Either A1, A2 or both are equal to ""
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Yupee" ' Both are not equal to "".
    End Select
End Sub
```